# What is the best practice of chain trigger

Tags: trigger, future

I had a scenario about 3 sObjects **(Opportunity, CustomProduct, CustomSample)**.

1. Both CustomProduct and CustomSample had lookup field to Opportunity.
    Each sObject have triggers (immediately and future method).
2. When I insert/update CustomSample data. It also update Opportunity
    and CustomProduct. Because future method, we only can update all 3 data
    in ONE process.
3. If we want to seperate the process. What is the best practice about     triggers and  handle future method? I found some posts are providing
    good structure of triggers.

   There are nothing about future method. Or the future method is not a
    good option?

If I am wrong, please give me suggestions.

**updated**:

- Insert/update CustomSample Process includes as below:

  1. CustomSample have before and after trigger, and after trigger will update Opportunity.
  2. Opportunity also have before and after trigger. In after trigger, it will update CustomProduct directly and indirectly(future method).
  3. CustomProduct have before and after trigger, too.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it is really difficult to understand what you are asking. It sounds like you are only working on one trigger? And you're worried about preexisting triggers on objects you touch through cross-object updates?

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson, sorry about that, there are 6 triggers. Your guess is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of good options for trigger patterns, [here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers) is one for example.

With regards to multiple future methods, I think you may want to look into using Queueable Apex instead of future methods [link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_queueing_jobs.htm). The key aspect of Queueable you're looking for is:

> Chaining jobs: You can chain one job to another job by starting a
>   second job from a running job. Chaining jobs is useful if you need to
>   do some processing that depends on another process to have run first.

Comment: Thx @Davinc, I never thought Queueable Apex can be applied to my case.